# Where does Edge Settings store the list of websites for which cookies must not be cleared when the browser is closed?

Tags: microsoft-edge

Where does Edge store the list of websites that are added at edge://settings/clearBrowsingDataOnClose ?

I do not find these in the registry, and I want to add to this list via a script or command - not manually/interactively through the Edge Settings UI.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the sites list under **Don't clear** on that page? If so, it's stored in a file called **Preferences**.

1. Find the location of the Preferences file. You can go to *edge://version/* and find the **Profile path**. The Preferences file is under that path.

[image]

2. Open Preferences file with Notepad and search for `clear_browsing_data_cookies_exceptions`. That's the value which controls the setting. For example, I set **Don't clear** list like below:

[image]

The values in the file are like this:

```
 "clear_browsing_data_cookies_exceptions":{"*,www.google.com":{"last_modified":"13321607962560793","setting":1},"www.bing.com,*":{"last_modified":"13321607952873922","setting":1}}
```

Note: The value of `last_modified` is WebKit/Chrome Timestamp.

---

**Update:**

Sample PowerShell code to edit the file:

```
$file = 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\your profile\Preferences'
$content = Get-Content -Path $file
$newContent = $content -replace 'clear_browsing_data_cookies_exceptions":{', 'clear_browsing_data_cookies_exceptions":{"www.stackoverflow.com,*":{"last_modified":"13321607962560794","setting":1},'
$newContent | Set-Content -Path $file
```

Please note that you need to use `taskkill /f /im msedge.exe` to kill all Edge process before editing the file.

**Registry Solution:**

This policy [Save cookies when Microsoft Edge closes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#savecookiesonexit) can edit this setting. The [corresponding registry setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#windows-registry-settings-421) is like below:

[image]

Note: This policy is only effective when:

- The 'Cookies and other site data' toggle is configured in Settings/Privacy and services/Clear browsing data on close or
- The policy [ClearBrowsingDataOnExit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#clearbrowsingdataonexit) is enabled or
- The policy [DefaultCookiesSetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#defaultcookiessetting) is set to 'Keep cookies for the duration of the session'.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Is there a way to add a website to the list from the command line or using some sort of script like PowerShell? It is tedious to add a large number of sites via the UI.

Alternatively, the repetetive "replace" of the string *"clear_browsing_data_cookies_exceptions":{* with something like "clear_browsing_data_cookies_exceptions":{"192.168.1.4,*":{"last_modified":"13316715107817621","setting":1},
may also work, but it's clunky.

Comment: @NutCracker Yes, you can add websites using PowerShell. I'm not very familiar with PowerShell and I can only think of the "replace" way. I'll edit my answer and you can check my sample code. Besides, I notice that you say "I do not find these in the registry", but I realize that we can do it via registry! I'll also update that solution in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This also works but has two issues:

1. The first entry must be added manually through the UI to deal with the comma at the end of the first entry.
2. The batch file only works if it first changes into the Profile Path folder.

```
    @echo off
    rem Add websites to Edge list of sites not to clear cookies for when closing.
    rem Manually add one site first before running the script to add the other sites - this deals with the comma at the end.
    
    cd "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default"
    set EdgeSettingsFile=Preferences
    
    rem call :AddSite 192.168.1.4 //Add this manually before running the script to add the other sites - this deals with the comma at the end.
    call :AddSite [*.]live.com
    call :AddSite [*.]microsoft.com
    call :AddSite [*.]microsoftonline.com
    call :AddSite [*.]office.com
    call :AddSite [*.]onenote.com
    call :AddSite [*.]youtube.com
    goto :end
    
    :AddSite
    set foo=\"clear_browsing_data_cookies_exceptions\":{
    set bar=\"clear_browsing_data_cookies_exceptions\":{\"%1,*\":{\"last_modified\":\"13316715107817621\",\"setting\":1},
    powershell -Command "(gc %EdgeSettingsFile%) -replace '%foo%', '%bar%' | Out-File -encoding ASCII %EdgeSettingsFile%"
    pause
    exit /B
    
    :end
    start "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %EdgeSettingsFile%
```